# Filtering Export Wizard availability by File extension

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using the **org.eclipse.ui.exportWizard** extension point in **Eclipse 3.5**.
When the user right-clicks on files in the workspace project explorer I only want my Export Wizard to be available if the **IFile** being selected has a particular extension.

I can use the **selection element** to define that the Wizard should only show up for an **IFile**. There is a '**name**' section, but if I try ***.my_ext** the wizard is still available for all **IFile**s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of this, but I think I recall that the name property is already a wildcard, so you should just be able to specify **.my_ext** as the name property.

Comment: Nope. Tried .my_ext and my_ext and *.my_ext  the wizard shows FOR ALL files extensions, whatever the case.